# Is there a command to copy the above line within terminal? (e.g. copy the output of pwd)

Tags: terminal, shell, copy-paste

Is there a command to copy the above line in terminal? This is a shell agnostic question (e.g. bash, zsh, etc.) basically I am using pwd and want to copy the output without having to type the long directory within my next command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash doesn't automatically store the stdout or stderr of the previous command. It mainly doesn't do this because of performance reasons. It could potentially take up a lot of RAM if the stdout output was very large, as is sometimes the case.

This is also why terminal emulators, everything from the built-in Linux VT up to `gnome-terminal`, impose a reasonably small limit on the amount of scrollback buffers (number of lines you can scroll up) before it "wraps".

Taking up that much RAM automatically and without user prompting would greatly slow down the shell for the many scripts and command sequences that *don't* require this particular behavior.

Instead, the user must know *in advance* that they want to store the stdout, and can then reference it in their later commands.

Two ways of doing this:

- `echo $(pwd)` -- in-line
- `MYPWD=$(pwd); echo ${MYPWD}` -- separate variable to capture output then reference it later

BTW, you might check the `PWD` environment variable. It may help you use way 2.

Comment: Thanks, I am currently using iTerm2 and "oh my zsh" -- however, using the two options that you suggested I am not seeing a way to paste the output into the prompt. e.g. if I use pwd and return the result /Users/Foo/Documents I am still not seeing the option to paste this into the prompt.